# Where are PTE flags defined (Linux)?

Tags: linux-kernel

The x86 PTE has two "AVL" fields that can be used by software (bits 62:52 and 11:9).  Does the Linux kernel use them?  If so, where in the source code are they defined?  I've looked in various page*.h files and can't find the PTE AVL fields defined.

Comment: Yes, of course. Otherwise it will be waste of resources.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7-rc2/source/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable_types.h#L12 It's architecture dependent code. Should I put an answer?